# Find substring anywhere in other column

Tags: pandas

I have strings in column `a`. I want to search all rows in column `b` to see if each value in `a` is found somewhere in `b`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"a":["hi","hello","yes","xyz"],
        "b":["asdfHI", "qwertHello","nononoXYZ", "OKOK"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#        a           b
# 0     hi      asdfHI
# 1  hello  qwertHello
# 2    yes   nononoXYZ
# 3    xyz        OKOK

#hi, hello and xyz is somewhere in b. Yes isnt. I want to create the found column:

#        a           b      found
# 0     hi      asdfHI      True
# 1  hello  qwertHello      True
# 2    yes   nononoXYZ      False
# 3    xyz        OKOK      True

#This only search rowwise so xyz isnt found:
df.apply(lambda x: x.a.lower() in x.b.lower(), axis=1)
# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2    False
# 3    False

#[aval.lower() in df.b.str.lower() for aval in df.a]
#[False, False, False, False]

#df.b.str.lower().str.contains(df.a.str.lower())
#TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

#df.b.str.contains(df.a.str, case=False)
#TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
B = df['b'].str.lower()
df['found'] = [any(a in b for b in B) for a in df['a'].str.lower()]
```

Or, join `b` with a separator which you know will be absent and use a simple `in` (this might be less efficient):

```
B = '||'.join(df['b'].str.lower())
df['found'] = [a in B for a in df['a'].str.lower()]
```

Output:

```
       a           b  found
0     hi      asdfHI   True
1  hello  qwertHello   True
2    yes   nononoXYZ  False
3    xyz        OKOK   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option, using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with [`char.find`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.char.find.html) :

```
words = df.to_numpy(dtype="str")

check = ~np.all(np.char.find(
    np.char.lower(words[:, 1, None]),
    np.char.lower(words[:, 0])) == -1, axis=0)

df["a in whole-b"] = check
```

Or maybe this variant with [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) / [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) & [membership operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) (*using* [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)) :

```
df["a in whole-b"] = [a.lower() in df["b"].str.cat().lower() for a in df["a"]]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

       a           b  a in whole-b
0     hi      asdfHI          True
1  hello  qwertHello          True
2    yes   nononoXYZ         False
3    xyz        OKOK          True
```

A perfplot (*of ~10k rows*) :

NumPy's approach is efficient on very small data and @mozway's are the fatest on larger one.

[image]

Comment: Interesting performance data - thanks for taking the time to measure it.